# SUM of grouped COUNT which only calaculate max value and display count of max

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 6 fields:

```
    partyname   state      constituency     candidatename   district    votes
    BJP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-East     Nitin Gadkari   Nagpur       1200
    AAP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-East     Arvind Kejriwal Nagpur       750
    BJP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-West     Vicky           Nagpur       4800
    AAP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-West     Lucky           Nagpur       3500
    BJP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-North    Rakesh          Nagpur       100
    AAP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-North    Ravan          Nagpur       1500
```

I want to group partyname ,constituency with 'count', and a row 'SUM'

**but it count only max value from each constituency and then display count and row sum.**

**below is my expected output for above table**

```
partyname       Count
    BJP          2

    AAP          1
```

**bcoz bjp leads from nagpur -east and nagpur west .so it display count 2 
and aap  leads from nagpur - north then it display only 1 count.**

plz suggest me query......

```
 <?php  
 $state =  $rowdst['state'];
 $sqlst = "SELECT  MAX(votes) AS Vote,constituency,state, district FROM voter_count where state = '$state' group by  constituency, state";
 $resultst = mysql_query($sqlst);
 while($rowst = mysql_fetch_array($resultst,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    ?>  
    <?php
             $vote = $rowst['Vote'];
             $sqlct = "SELECT COUNT($vote) AS counts,partyname,constituency, district FROM voter_count where votes = '$vote' AND state = '$state'";
             $resultct = mysql_query($sqlct);
             $rowct = mysql_fetch_array($resultct,MYSQL_ASSOC)
        ?>    
             <tr>  
              <td><?php echo $rowct['partyname']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rowct['counts']; ?></td>
        </tr>  
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't see constituency in your result set, and note that PHP's mysql_ API is long since deprecated.

Comment: maharashtra vidhan sabha election 2014 fever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don’t care about same votes count for different parties (handling the same votes count for different parties in the same district would make the query far more complicated, because you will get unpredictable value for `MAX` column in the inner query):

```
SELECT RES.PARTYNAME, COUNT(RES.CONSTITUENCY) AS VOTESCOUNT
FROM voter_count RES
JOIN (
    SELECT CONSTITUENCY, MAX(VOTES) AS VOTES
    FROM voter_count
    GROUP BY CONSTITUENCY
) MAXS USING(VOTES, CONSTITUENCY)
GROUP BY PARTYNAME;
```

First of all, the inner query selects maximal values for `votes`. The result of inner query execution would be:

```
Nagpur-East,1200
Nagpur-North,1500
Nagpur-West,4800
```

After that, join maximals and count districts.

```
AAP,1
BJP,2
```

Comment: how to echo this count and partname from above query   i am new in php .plz sugget me.....

Comment: Exactly as you did, column names in the result are `PARTYNAME` and `VOTESCOUNT`. BTW, the question you posted states “plz suggest me query.”

Comment: SELECT RES.PARTYNAME, COUNT(RES.CONSTITUENCY) AS VOTESCOUNT
FROM voter_count RES
JOIN (
    SELECT CONSTITUENCY, MAX(VOTES) AS VOTES
    FROM voter_count
    GROUP BY CONSTITUENCY
) MAXS USING(VOTES)
GROUP BY PARTYNAME how to echo output from above query

Comment: What did you try? `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultst,MYSQL_ASSOC))` etc works perfectly.

Comment: i ask you how to display this for ex like this or other <?php echo $rowst['VOTESCOUNT']; ?>  i paste above query in var $sqlst but it shows me error like mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Comment: In the question you posted you have asked how the query should look like. The question “how to execute queries with PHP” is not the same. The answer to latter may be easily googled. BTW, this is not the site “write code for me for free.”

Comment: SELECT RES.PARTYNAME, COUNT(RES.CONSTITUENCY) AS VOTESCOUNT
FROM voter_count RES
JOIN (
    SELECT CONSTITUENCY, MAX(VOTES) AS VOTES
    FROM voter_count
    GROUP BY CONSTITUENCY
) MAXS USING(VOTES)
GROUP BY PARTYNAME this query is working fine but there is certain problem on this..    if same vote comes to same party in differenctconstituency then this shoes wrong output

Comment: I have said in advance, that same votes values would lead to problems. See updated (more complicated, though my intention was to keep the way to solve problem as clear aspossible) query, now it returns proper results for same votes count in different districts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution for Your Problem.. Hope this will work..

```
select t1.partyname as PARTY, count(*) as WinCount
from voter_count t1, voter_count t2 where t1.votes > t2.votes
and t1.constituency=t2.constituency
group by t1.partyname
```

Comment: This works for two parties only. plz tell me if there is only single party then what we do.....plz suggest propery query...

Comment: @rajmalhotra: `select partyname as PARTY, count(*) as WinCount
from voter_count where partyname='BJP' group by partyname`  If its not, then what exactly You wanna say ?  I didn't get..

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question its difficult to understand what exactly you want as output result

```
SELECT partyname AS 'Party Name',COUNT(candidatename) AS 'can_count',SUM(votes) AS 'sum'
FROM voter_count 
WHERE votes >= 1500
GROUP BY constituency
ORDER BY can_count DESC;
```

also check this [SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4be2c/17)

hope this query will help you to get desired output..

Comment: @mudasobwa WTF is WTF ??